# Issue with BufferedReader.read while reading from InputStream

Tags: inputstream, bufferedreader

I am trying to read input stream in chunks and write to file to avoid memory issue, I am receiving data in json format and same I write to file using following code.

```
BufferedReader rd =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    if(getOutputFormat().equals(Constants.URI_FORMAT_JSON)){

    boolean enableAppend = true;
    CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.allocate(1024);
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new      FileWriter(request.getJsonFile(isNewFile),enableAppend));
    int readState = 0;
    while ((readState = rd.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        buffer.flip();

        if(isNewFile){
            writer.write(buffer.toString());
            isNewFile = false;
        }else {
            writer.append(buffer.toString());
        }
        buffer.clear();
    }

    writer.newLine();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close(); 
}
```

My problem is, most of the json is written fine, **while some of them contains broken data**, I am not sure if I am correctly using CharBuffer with BufferedReader, One more thing I have observed is, for small amount of data - it correctly takes into CharBuffer and writes to file, mostly I face it when I move with bit bigger data (around 2MB in inputstream - Not very big) received from server. Also verified using readLine method which works fine, but I want to read data in chunks hence using CharBuffer, Any idea?

Comment: You should use `compact()`, not `clear()` in general loops of this kind, but it won't make any difference in this speific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging found that "connection reset" was happening in middle hence data lose. Handled the exception to make a controlled retry for the same request and problem got resolved. Hope it helps to somebody.